# Mathematics behind spin-functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin

In texts concerning electronic structure calculations, usually the spin-functions $\alpha({\omega})$ and $\beta(\omega)$ are introduced as being functions of the "unspecified spin variable $\omega$" and having the properties$^{[1]}$. 
$$\int d\omega \; \alpha^*(\omega)\alpha(\omega) = \int d\omega \; \beta^*(\omega)\beta(\omega) = 1 \; ,$$
$$\int d\omega \; \alpha^*(\omega)\beta(\omega) = \int d\omega \; \beta^*(\omega)\alpha(\omega) = 0 \; .$$
In the following these functions are treated as any other function of a variable $\omega$ so that constructions like 
$$|\Psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ \varphi_1(\pmb{r}_1)\varphi_2(\pmb{r}_2) +\varphi_1(\pmb{r}_2)\varphi_2(\pmb{r}_1)\right] \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ \alpha(\omega_1)\beta(\omega_2)-\beta(\omega_1)\alpha(\omega_2) \right]$$
are possible.
From what I know spin is best represented by a vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and $n$-spins by $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$. In that sense I wonder how the notation of $\alpha({\omega})$ and $\beta(\omega)$ are mathematically justified and what I can think of a product like $\beta(\omega_1)\alpha(\omega_1)$. I know that this notation seems to work quite well but I am not sure how the treatment of spin as a simple function, that you can factor out etc., is justified.

$^{[1]}$ Szabo, A., Ostlund, N.S. (1996). *Modern Quantum Chemistry: Introduction to Advanced Electronic Structure Theory*.